Is crossbeam_epoch Atomic really atomic?
I have a requirement to store a complex struct as config globally. Struct will be mostly read and seldom write. So, i am exploring if i can use crossbeam_epoch::Atomic to store global config, share config across threads. I was testing if read/write to crossbeam_epoch::Atomic is atomic or not.
I created a Config struct with version:i32 property. I created 5 threads and in each threads incremented version of config by 1 for 100 times in a tight loop. I was expecting that at the completion of every thread, i'll get 500 as result. But, results were random.
use crossbeam_epoch as epoch;
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering;
use std::{sync::Arc, thread};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Config {
    version: i32,
}

fn run() -> () {
    let atomic = Arc::new(epoch::Atomic::new(Config { version: 0 }));

    let mut handles = vec![];

    let per_thread_itr = 100;
    let num_thread = 5;

    for _ in 0..num_thread {
        let thread_handle = thread::spawn({
            let atomic = atomic.clone();
            move || {
                let guard = epoch::pin();
                for _ in 1..per_thread_itr + 1 {
                    let shared = atomic.load(Ordering::SeqCst, &guard);
                    if let Some(v) = unsafe { shared.as_ref() } {
                        atomic.store(
                            epoch::Owned::new(Config {
                                version: v.version + 1,
                            }),
                            Ordering::SeqCst,
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        handles.push(thread_handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    // Main thread accesses the updated value
    let guard = epoch::pin();
    let result = unsafe { atomic.load(Ordering::SeqCst, &guard).as_ref() }.unwrap();

    println!("Result: {}", result.version);
}

fn main() {
    for _ in 0..5 {
        run();
    }
}

Result:
Result: 297
Result: 398
Result: 349
Result: 235
Result: 365

When using std::sync::atomic::AtomicI32
While the same approach worked for std::sync::atomic::AtomicI32.
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicI32;
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

fn run() {
    // Use AtomicI32 with proper atomic operations
    let atomic = Arc::new(AtomicI32::new(0));

    let mut handles = vec![];

    let per_thread_itr = 100;
    let num_thread = 5;

    for _ in 0..num_thread {
        let a = atomic.clone();
        let thread_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            for _ in 0..per_thread_itr {
                // Safely increment the atomic value
                a.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
            }
        });

        handles.push(thread_handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("Result: {}", atomic.load(Ordering::SeqCst));
}

fn main() {
    for _ in 0..5 {
        run();
    }
}

**Result : **
Result: 500
Result: 500
Result: 500
Result: 500
Result: 500

So, i was wondering if crossbeam_epoch::Atomic works differently than std::sync::atomic::AtomicI32 or not? Or am i missing something here?

Atomic<T> is a pointer type, it doesn't magically make access to wrapped T atomic by default. What it does, it allows one to atomically operate on the pointer to heap allocation where T is stored. So basically it's like AtomicUsize, where the value is a pointer to T.
If you want to modify T in such a way that modification depends on previous state, you have to use CAS loop. Otherwise you will most certainly have a race, as modifications will interleave and result in unexpected states of T.
Here's an updated version of your code using compare exchange approach. This always produces the result you would expect.
use crossbeam_epoch as epoch;
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering;
use std::{sync::Arc, thread};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Config {
    version: i32,
}

fn run() {
    let atomic = Arc::new(epoch::Atomic::new(Config { version: 0 }));

    let mut handles = vec![];

    let per_thread_itr = 100;
    let num_thread = 5;

    for _ in 0..num_thread {
        let thread_handle = thread::spawn({
            let atomic = atomic.clone();
            move || {
                let guard = epoch::pin();
                for _ in 0..per_thread_itr {
                    let mut shared = atomic.load(Ordering::Acquire, &guard);
                    let mut value = unsafe { shared.as_ref() }.unwrap();

                    while let Err(state) = atomic.compare_exchange(
                        shared,
                        epoch::Owned::new(Config {
                            version: value.version + 1,
                        }),
                        Ordering::Release,
                        Ordering::Acquire,
                        &guard,
                    ) {
                        shared = state.current;
                        value = unsafe { shared.as_ref() }.unwrap();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        handles.push(thread_handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    // Main thread accesses the updated value
    let guard = epoch::pin();
    let result = unsafe { atomic.load(Ordering::Acquire, &guard).as_ref() }.unwrap();

    println!("Result: {}", result.version);
}

fn main() {
    for _ in 0..5 {
        run();
    }
}


Thanks this answered my question

Each read and write is atomic, but your operation of incrementing the value is not since you're doing two separate operations (read, then write). What can happen is that inbetween the read and the write another thread could have updated your variable, making you losing one of two updates.
This is not a data race, since all accesses are atomic, but it's a race condition because as a whole the operation of incrementing a value can race with another one producing non-intended results.
You'll get similar results with AtomicI32 and other atomic types if you do separate calls to load and store. In comparison, fetch_add is a single atomic operations that as a whole fetches the value, increments it and writes it back.
In order to emulate what fetch_add does (which is specialized for numeric types and supported by hardware instructions) you'll need a compare_exchange (CAS) loop. The key point is that you don't just write back the updated value, but instead in a single atomic operation you check if the value is still the one you initially read, and if so you update the atomic variable with the new value. This can however fail, hence the need for a loop that retries until it succeeds.
This pattern is also conveniently wrapped in a fetch_update method, both in crossbeam and the standard library.
